# How to create a database column that is valid for a certain period?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

Let's say, I want to create a mobile no verification system. I am sending a one-time-password to the user to verify his/her mobile no. I want that to be valid only for 15 minutes. What I want is a database column which data will be valid only for 15 minutes, after that, it will automatically become null. How can I achieve this?
I am using laravel with MySQL. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could store a datetime (sound of penny dropping)

Comment: Yeah, I was already doing that. But what if I want to change the UI based on the database data. I have to send a new request every time.

Comment: I don't follow.

Comment: @Strawberry ok, then what if I want to change my otp or token after every 15 minutes....?

Comment: You dont need it to become null,just compare the stored time to current time

Comment: Aside from the fact that I don't know the answers to these problems, these questions are simply too broad for SO. Start with any of the thousand or so tutorials on 2FA, and come back when you have some code, and a specific problem.